# Android EditText - decimal separator

Tags: java, android

I have two EditTexts. In the first one, the user inputs a number, can be a decimal. In the second EditText, the number is displayed, but formatted, rounded. I made the second EditText not clickable since the user shouldn't be able to change this value. I prefer to use an EditText instead of a TextView because of the style. The problem is with foreign numbers with a comma decimal error. My app is getting this error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "1,60934"` by people who use a comma separator.

> XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/value1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/value2"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static EditText value1;
    public static EditText value2;
    public static double value1var;
    public static double value2var;
    public static DecimalFormat df;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        df = new DecimalFormat("0.#####", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.FRANCE));

        value1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value1);
        value2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.value2);

        value1.setText(df.format(1.0));
        value2.setText(df.format(1000));

        value1var = Double.parseDouble(value1.getText().toString());
        value2var = Double.parseDouble(value2.getText().toString());

        value1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String value = s.toString();
                double valuevar = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());

                if(value.length() > 0){
                    value2.setText(df.format(valuevar));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

According to this part of code:

```
value1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String value = s.toString();
                double valuevar = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());

                if(value.length() > 0){
                    value2.setText(df.format(valuevar));
                }
            }
```

As you noticed, Java throws an exception if there's a comma separator.

To fix this problem, add if given string has comma, I mean write code like this

```
if (value1.contains(",")) {
//Here implement `for` loop, which would check which char of string has this problematic sign.

//Use string.charAt(i) function to compare

// use string.replace(int begin, int end, CharSequence cs) function to change it to point instead of comma.\
}
```

You can also prompt a user with `AlertDialog` if comma char would be detected, but as you may think it won't fix this problem entirely as changing automatically this char.

Play with `String` and `Dialogs` to make a validation of these fields.

Hope it help